# Tableview custom row names

Tags: xcode, tableview, row

I am making an app where I'll have a tableview with an 'add' button in the navigation bar, and this 'add' button creates a new row, but the problem is I can't figure out how to give rows unique names. To let the user decide the name, I have included an alert with a plain text field. The user should then write the name in the field and the new row will then be called that. But how do I do that?
I have used the tableview template provided in Xcode, which give each row a new name according to the clock they added a new row. I'll just want a alert to pop up first and then let the user type the name for the new row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify each row somehow. One way is to use the index in the table as the identifier. I guess your adding the row to a NSArray which is mapped to the table rows or something similar, so you know the index of the new row. You only have to update the row of that index using this method on your UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Assuming you have only one section, your array is called 'arrayWithRowsData' and you put the new row at the end, you can create the index path with:

```
int newRowIndex = [arrayWithRowsData count] - 1;
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
```

Hope it helps.